# Unable to Make SQL Connection

Tags: sql, connection

Having Trouble making sql connection. this is my code

```
 private static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + path + @"\App_Data\Database1.sdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    con.Open();

    return con;
}
```

and this is what i get

> Error: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   \App_Data\Database1.sdf failed. A database with the same name exists,
>   or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

And my database is located in a folder App_Data so not sure whats wrong

Comment: what does the variable "path" contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might cover the issues you are facing...

[msdn on sql express](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/f21c0728-935d-492a-baaf-ff2704e3683b/)

Sorry for the link but I didn't want to just copy paste someone elses findings...